# Using regex in filter in Julia

Tags: regex, lambda, filter, match, julia

It is possible to filter items that fits a simple condition to match strings in Julia:

```
y = ["1 123","2512","31 12","1225"]
filter(x-> ' ' in x, y)
```

[out]:

```
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "1 123"
 "31 12"
```

**But how do I get the reverse where I want to keep the items that doesn't match the condition in a filter?**

This syntax isn't right:

```
> y = ["1 123","2512","31 12","1225"]
> filter(x-> !' ' in x, y)
MethodError: no method matching !(::Char)
Closest candidates are:
  !(::Bool) at bool.jl:16
  !(::BitArray{N}) at bitarray.jl:1036
  !(::AbstractArray{Bool,N}) at arraymath.jl:30
  ...

 in filter(::##93#94, ::Array{String,1}) at ./array.jl:1408
```

Neither is such Python-like one:

```
> y = ["1 123","2512","31 12","1225"]
> filter(x-> ' ' not in x, y)
syntax: missing comma or ) in argument list
```

Additionally, I've also tried to use a regex:

```
> y = ["1 123","2512","31 12","1225"]
> filter(x-> match(r"[\s]", x), y)
TypeError: non-boolean (RegexMatch) used in boolean context
in filter(::##95#96, ::Array{String,1}) at ./array.jl:1408
```

Beyond checking whether a whitespace is in string, **how can I use the `match()` with a regex to filter out items from a list of strings?**

Comment: the expected output is `["2512", "1225"]` , right?

Comment: yep. it's `["2512", "1225"]` but the question is more generic asking about how to use `filter()` with `match()` conditions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order:

1. `filter(x-> !' ' in x, y)`. The precedence is wrong here. The error message is telling you that it's trying to apply the `!` function to a single `Char` argument: `(!' ') in x`. You need explicit parentheses:

   ```
    julia> filter(x-> !(' ' in x), y)
    2-element Array{String,1}:
     "2512"
     "1225"
   ```
2. `filter(x-> ' ' not in x, y)`. `not` isn't a keyword in Julia.
3. `filter(x-> match(r"[\s]", x), y)`. The error is telling you that it expected a boolean value but didn't get one.  Unlike Python, Julia doesn't have "truthy" values.  So instead of `match`, use [`contains`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.contains).

   ```
   julia> filter(!contains(r"[\s]"), y)
   2-element Vector{String}:
    "2512"
    "1225"
   ```

Comment: Cool, BTW, does Julia have Noney values?

Comment: Nope, just `true` and `false`.

Comment: In Julia 1.0 this would be `filter(x -> match(r"[\s]", x) === nothing, y)`

Comment: Slightly simpler is `filter(!contains(r"[\s]"), y)`.